# why can't i access the pointer to a structure from another file and get the members

Tags: c, static, malloc, external

this a reproducible example and not the entire code the entire code is too large..
my problem was that i had a structure that i created using malloc and i needed to access it from another function in another file, but i keep getting segfault...

header file
**main.h**

```
#ifndef main_a
#define main_a
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct cmd_s
{
     int n;
} cmd_t;

extern cmd_t *ptr;
void push(char *line);

#endif
```

the main.c file
**main.c**

```
#include "main.h"
cmd_t *ptr = NULL;

int main(void)
{
    cmd_t *ptr = malloc(sizeof(cmd_t));
    ptr->n = 5;
    push("line");
    
    return (0);
}
```

and where i need to access the struct from named opcode.c

**opcode.c**

```
#include "main.h"

void push(char *line)
{
    int new = ptr->n;
}
```

note that this is not the actual code the actual code has useful values, this is an example that contains the challenge i am facing

i tried to use static instead but i got the same error.
i'm still a novice in c programming..
and i don't want to change the way i created the structure, which is through malloc because another function depends on it... i just need to make that malloced structure accessible to another file in the program.
thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can use that variable from the second file exactly as you tried to do. The issue is in `main`: `cmd_t *ptr = malloc...` This introduces another variable named `ptr` that is not related to your global variable at all. Remove the `cmd_t*` in that line.

Comment: There clearly must be a dupe somewhere....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main(void)
{
    cmd_t *ptr = malloc(sizeof(cmd_t));
```

You create new `ptr` variable visible only in function `main`. Your `push` see the global pointer `ptr` but not the one you have `malloc`ed.

You need to

```
int main(void)
{
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
    /* .... */
```

Use ***obiects*** not ***types*** in `sizeof` (as in this example)

Comment: And if you use an object as the operand for the _operator_ `sizeof`, omit the parentheses.

Comment: @thebusybee no- I prefer this way